Reading/writing Polars data frame with list column from/to database
Writing a df with a list column like so
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[['A','B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]})
df.write_database(
    "test", "sqlite:///test.db",
    if_table_exists = "replace",
)

works fine, but then running
pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT * FROM test", uri="sqlite://test.db")

gives the error
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Blob at index: 1, name: b

I cannot seem to get around this by using engine_options in write_database to specify that I want a list field (not a blob), nor by using schema_overrides in the read_database_uri. What is the correct way to write/read this sort of data frame with list column(s)?

Could you pls run DESCRIBE test and print out table information? I believe that the column b should be a BLOB. This is expected, because SQLite can't store arrays (can't serialize them). Thus problem is why you can't read the blob from 'b'

I believe that that in your case you'll need to save list of strings as BLOB in MySQL lite and later somehow decode bytes back to list. However there is two problems:

polars standard protocol connectorx can't read BLOB columns, thus you need to swith to adbc
Even after switching to adbc it is not clear how to convert BLOB back to bytes.

Thus I would propose to merge list of string with any separator and store strings as VARCHAR and later convert back:
import polars as pl

SEP = "\t"

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[['A','B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]})

# mapping: List[str] -> str
df = df.with_columns(b = pl.col('b').list.join(SEP))
df.write_database(
    "test", "sqlite:///test.db",
    if_table_exists = "replace",
)

ff = pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT a,b FROM test", 
                          uri="sqlite://test.db",
                              )

# mapping: str -> List[str]
ff = ff.with_columns(pl.col('b').str.split(SEP))


Alternatively:
Or serialize the column to json and again save it in dabase as VARCHAR - later deserialise back
import json
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[['A','B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]})

# dump to json
f = lambda x: json.dumps(list(x))
df = df.with_columns(b = pl.col('b').apply(f))


df.write_database(
    "test", "sqlite:///test.db",
    if_table_exists = "replace",
)

ff = pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT a,b FROM test", 
                          uri="sqlite://test.db",
                              )


ff = ff.with_columns(pl.col('b').str.json_decode())

Alternative 2:
Prepare the column by converting it to binary object before saving it in sql database. Column will be saved as BLOB.
import pickle 
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[['A','B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]})

# dump column to binary object
df = df.with_columns(b = pl.col('b').apply(pickle.dumps))


df.write_database(
    "test", "sqlite:///test.db",
    if_table_exists = "replace",
)

ff = pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT a,b FROM test", 
                          uri="sqlite://test.db",
                          engine='adbc', # need to use adbc engine instead of standard
                              )
ff = ff.with_columns(pl.col('b').apply(pickle.loads))

